# If the $p$-core of a finite group $G$ is trivial, what can be deduced from that about $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

I am looking for (textbook) references for the following situation:

> If $G$ is a finite group and its $p$-core $\mathcal{O}_p(G)$ is trivial, what can be deduced from this about $G$?

(Do groups with this property have a special name?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very little, I'm afraid. For example, $G$ could be a $q$-group for some prime $q\neq p$. Or it could be a simple group, or a symmetric group. Notice that the group $G/O_p(G)$ always has your property.

Do you have it in any specific context? For example, a group with no $p$-core as the centralizer of a $q$-element in a simple group?

Comment: Oh ok, that's a pitty. I don't have any specific context, but I would be particularly interested in the case $p=2$. Is the situation any better then? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not particularly. The main use for the $p$-core was in fact for all primes other than $2$. Define $O(G)$ to be the product of the $p$-cores for $p\neq 2$, called the *core* of $G$. If $t$ is an element of order $2$ in a simple group $G$, then one is interested in the structure of $H=C_G(t)$, and in particular $H/O(H)$. Part of the big issue in the classification of finite simple groups was the fact that $O(H)$ can be non-trivial. If it were not then lots of knotty problems go away.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.